# angular1 testing directive with gettextCatalog loadRemote

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angularjs-e2e

I am using Angular 1.5.8 with es6 syntax and `angular-gettext` module for multilanguage support. In my switch-language directive I load translated content via

`` this.gettextCatalog.loadRemote(`assets/languages/${this.LanguageService.currentLanguage}.json`); ``

watch and build (via gulp) works fine, everything is as it should be, but once I run `gulp test` I receive an error:

**Error: Unexpected request: GET assets/languages/sr_RS@cyrillic.json**

For testing I use karma:

```
beforeEach(inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {

    element = angular.element(`
      <lang-switcher></lang-switcher>
    `);

    $compile(element)($rootScope.$new());
    $rootScope.$digest();
    vm = element.isolateScope().vm;
  }));

  it('should be compiled', () => {
    expect(element.html()).not.toEqual(null);
  });
```

each time i run my gulp test task I receive the above error. I guess it happens during compile process since my switchLang directive tries to get external data using $http.get from angular-gettext module. How this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to mock any external requests that are made when unit testing. e.g.

```
var $httpBackend;
var mockJson = { }; // You can specify the mocked response for "sr_RS@cyrillic.json" if necessary

beforeEach(inject(($compile, $rootScope, $httpBackend) => {
    element = angular.element(`
        <lang-switcher></lang-switcher>
    `);

    $compile(element)($rootScope.$new());
    $rootScope.$digest();
    vm = element.isolateScope().vm;

    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/languages/sr_RS@cyrillic.json').respond(mockJson);
}));
```